# stationary point of a periodic function.

Tags: calculus

I have a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which is periodic with period $2\pi$, how to show that there exists a point $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f(x_0)=f(x_0+\pi)$?

I defined the function $g(x)=f(x)-f(x+\pi)$, I want to show that this function vanishes in some point. So I need to find an interval $[a,b]$ where $g(a)g(b)<0$, but how?

I think I had such a question when I took the course but I cannot find my notes from that course.

Comment: This has always been a major problem for me in my classes, but isn't this kind of self-evident from the term periodic?

Comment: Suppose $g(0)>0$ and the minimum of $f(x)$ is attained at $x_0\in [0, 2\pi)$.  If $g(x_0)>0$ that would mean that $f(x_0)>f(x_0+\pi)$.

Comment: @lulu I don't see your point.

Comment: Well, my argument shows that $g(x_0)$ can not be positive so....

Comment: ah, ok I see $g(0)>0$ and $g(x_0)\le 0$ so we can use the IVT.

Comment: @MartinR yes indeed so do you think I need to delete my post?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist: No. But there should be a button where you can confirm that it is a duplicate.